# if (user == 'y'){} keeps running even if it does not equal 'y'

Tags: c++, if-statement

this is the full code. when the user enters u into the menu, he is prompted by a y or n, for being a new user. The y works fine, and writes the information to file properly, but the "n" does not. If u type "n" it gives you the options for the "y", which it should be ignoring. but it isnt...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string first, last, gender, loginid, pass;
char menu, user;
int pid, passScore;

const string inFileErrMsg = "\nExisting User Input File Error!\n\n";
const string exitMsg = "\nExiting the Application\n";
const string mobAppMsg = "\n Mobile App Sales: ProjectWon.\n";
const string gameMsg = "\n  ...COMING SOON!...\n  PROJECT-game-THREE\n"
"~revenge of the project~";

int main() {
    ofstream outfile("currUser.txt");
    while (menu != 'x') {
        cout << "\n==================================";
        cout << "\n- Choose from one of the following:";
        cout << "\n\tEnter u for User Information.";
        cout << "\n\tEnter m for Mobile App Sales.";
        cout << "\n\tEnter g for GameTime.";
        cout << "\n\tEnter x to Exit the program.";
        cout << "\n==================================";
        cout << "\n>";

        cin >> menu;

        menu = tolower(menu);
        switch (menu){
        case 'g':
            cout << gameMsg << endl;
            break;
        case 'm':
            cout << mobAppMsg << endl;
            break;
        case 'u':
            cout << "Are you a new user (y or n)?" << endl;
            cin >> user;
            user = tolower(user);
            while (user = 'y' || 'n') {
                if (user = 'y'){
                    ifstream file;
                    ofstream newuser;
                    string username, password, passwordconfirm;
                    file.open("currUser.txt", ios::app);
                    newuser.open("currUser.txt", ios::app);
                    bool uservalid = false;
                    while (!uservalid)
                    {
                        cout << "First Name: ";
                        cin >> first;
                        cout << "Last Name: ";
                        cin >> last;
                        cout << "Gender: ";
                        cin >> gender;

                        gender = toupper(gender[0]);

                        loginid = first[0] + last + gender[0];
                        username = loginid;
                        cout << "Password: ";
                        cin >> password;

                        if (gender == "m"){
                            pid = 2 * (1000 + rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1));
                        }
                        else{
                            pid = 2 * (1000 + rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1;
                        }

                        uservalid = true;
                    }
                    newuser << first << " " << last << " " << gender << " " << pid << " " << username << " " << password << endl;

                    cout << "\nUser Login: " << username << "\n";
                    cout << "\nName: " << first << " " << last;
                    cout << "\nPID: " << pid << "  Gender: " << gender;
                    cout << "\nUser Password: " << password << "\t";

                    file.close();
                    newuser.close();
                    break;
                }
                if (user = 'n'){
                    ifstream file;
                    string userid, password;
                    int n = 0;
                    file.open("currUser.txt");
                    if (file.is_open())
                    {
                        while (!file.eof())
                        {
                            file >> first >> last >> gender >> pid >> userid >> password;
                            n++;
                            if (loginid == userid && pass == password)
                                return n;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (user != 'n' || user != 'y')
                    {
                        cout << inFileErrMsg << endl;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            };
            break;
        case 'x':
            cout << exitMsg << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            return(0);
        default: break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `=` vs. `==`. I'm surprised your compiler didn't issue a warning on this.

Comment: Well, did you consider to step through this code using a decent debugger before asking here?

Comment: Your question says `if (user == 'y')` but your code reads `if (user = 'y' || 'n')` which assign `'y'` to `user`.

Comment: im using visual studio express 2013, is it bad??

Comment: The variable `menu` is not initialized before the `while` loop.

Comment: I do not use express but I would have expected a warning for that code.

Answer (score 2):

You have assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` throughout your code.

And this:

```
while (user = 'y' || 'n')
```

should be this

```
while (user == 'y' || user == 'n')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, wherever you have used conditions(inside if and while), make sure you are checking equality and not assigning values. There are 2 such ifs and 1 such while where you have assigned the R.H.S. to the L.H.S. instead of checking their equality.